# What is this Korean board game?

Tags: identify-this-game

This picture is from North Korea:

[image]

What is the game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't speak for the pieces since the picture doesn't show much of any detail on those (except that they're probably homemade), but that definitely looks like a [Janggi board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janggi):
[image: Janggi board yanked from Wikipedia]